# displaying <div> in transparent popUp

Tags: html

i need to display the  section as PopUp while  onload(). but i don't know how to call this javascript function(function($)). name has confused me. also if any other way to call this div section  as popup .please sugesst. Thanks

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
    // function name is function($)
    function($){
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <!-- body of the popUp -->    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`$`](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#Launching_Code_on_Document_Ready) function is probably the one defined in [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), so you will need to include the jQuery JavaScript library if you *want* to use it for showing a pop up.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Including *just* this library will define the `$` function and you can then use jQuery functions in your  JavaScript code. However this will not create a pop-up. There are [many jQuery plugins](http://choosedaily.com/1178/15-jquery-popup-modal-dialog-plugins-tutorials/) that can be used to create a pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery dialog?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Loads of examples on there